# How to import content with system user?

Tags: java, aem, sling

I have following project structure:
[image]

`content.xml` file content looks so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:rep="internal"
    jcr:mixinTypes="[rep:AccessControllable]"
    jcr:primaryType="rep:system">
    <rep:privileges/>
    <jcr:versionStorage/>
    <rep:permissionStore jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore">
        <crx.default jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore">
            <trololo1 jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore">
                <_x002d_2124328162
                    jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore"
                    rep:accessControlledPath="/system">
                    <_x0032_
                        jcr:primaryType="rep:Permissions"
                        rep:isAllow="{Boolean}true"
                        rep:privileges="{Long}[2105343]"/>
                </_x002d_2124328162>
                <_x0031_259237738
                    jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore"
                    rep:accessControlledPath="/content">
                    <_x0031_8
                        jcr:primaryType="rep:Permissions"
                        rep:isAllow="{Boolean}true"
                        rep:privileges="{Long}[2105343]"/>
                </_x0031_259237738>
                <_x0031_500933
                    jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore"
                    rep:accessControlledPath="/etc">
                    <_x0034_
                        jcr:primaryType="rep:Permissions"
                        rep:isAllow="{Boolean}true"
                        rep:privileges="{Long}[2105343]"/>
                </_x0031_500933>
                <_x0031_515144
                    jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore"
                    rep:accessControlledPath="/tmp">
                    <_x0032_
                        jcr:primaryType="rep:Permissions"
                        rep:isAllow="{Boolean}true"
                        rep:privileges="{Long}[2105343]"/>
                </_x0031_515144>
                <_x0031_516696
                    jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore"
                    rep:accessControlledPath="/var">
                    <_x0033_
                        jcr:primaryType="rep:Permissions"
                        rep:isAllow="{Boolean}true"
                        rep:privileges="{Long}[2105343]"/>
                </_x0031_516696>
                <_x0034_6406433
                    jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore"
                    rep:accessControlledPath="/apps">
                    <_x0035_
                        jcr:primaryType="rep:Permissions"
                        rep:isAllow="{Boolean}true"
                        rep:privileges="{Long}[2105343]"/>
                </_x0034_6406433>
                <_x0034_6464979
                    jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore"
                    rep:accessControlledPath="/conf">
                    <_x0032_
                        jcr:primaryType="rep:Permissions"
                        rep:isAllow="{Boolean}true"
                        rep:privileges="{Long}[2105343]"/>
                </_x0034_6464979>
                <_x0034_6613902
                    jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore"
                    rep:accessControlledPath="/home">
                    <_x0038_
                        jcr:primaryType="rep:Permissions"
                        rep:isAllow="{Boolean}true"
                        rep:privileges="{Long}[2105343]"/>
                </_x0034_6613902>
                <_x0034_6726973
                    jcr:primaryType="rep:PermissionStore"
                    rep:accessControlledPath="/libs">
                    <_x0034_
                        jcr:primaryType="rep:Permissions"
                        rep:isAllow="{Boolean}true"
                        rep:privileges="{Long}[2105343]"/>
                </_x0034_6726973>
            </trololo1>
        </crx.default>
    </rep:permissionStore>
    <rep:policy/>
    <jcr:activities/>
    <jcr:nodeTypes/>
    <rep:namespaces/>
</jcr:root>
```

When I am trying to deploy content on cq I see the following error:

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.PackageException: javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: Item is protected.
```

Is it possible to deploy system user from content?

### P.S.

Problem appeared after migration from 6.0 to 6.1

I need to add new system user with wide permissions and write it in `Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service   Apache Sling Service User Mapper` configuration instead of admin to avoid problem with `slingRepository.loginService`